# Apply optimization function to data frame

Tags: r, optimization, vectorization

I have a one dimensional function f(x), which I want to maximize for a certain range of values x in (0,1 ..., 10) for different paramater values, which are in columns of a data frame. Each row of the data frame represents one set of paramters for which I want to maximize the function.

A stylized example of my data is as follows:

```
| a  | b   | c | n  |
|----|-----|---|----|
| 2  | 1.5 | 1 | 2  |
| -1 | 2   | 1 | 3  |
| 1  | 0.5 | 1 | 20 |
```

And the function I want to apply

```
minmax <- function(x, a, n, b, c) ((20+a*x)+(15+b*x)+n*(30-c*x))
```

So far I  have created the following function, which saves both the maximized value and the objective function. My question is: 
How should I change the code, such that it only saves the value for which the function is maximized and append the results to the existing data frame  ?

```
for (i in 1:46){ 
    min.max.value[[i]]   <- optimize(minmax, c(0, 10),  a = data.2$a[i], 
    n=data.2$n[i], b=data.2$b[i], c=data.2$c[i], maximum=T)
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the source code of how I reformatted your answer: code on Stack Overflow is formatted properly by indenting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data only has numeric values, you can use it as a matrix and then `apply` the `optmize` function over the rows, saving only the optmized value of `x`.

Data:

```
mat <- matrix(c(2, -2, 1, 1.5, 2, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 20), ncol=4)
colnames(mat) <- c("a", "b", "c", "n")
```

Functions:

```
minmax <- function(x, a, n, b, c) ((20+a*x)+(15+b*x)+n*(30-c*x))
opt <- apply(mat, 1, function(i) {
  optimize(minmax, c(0, 10),  a = i[["a"]], n=i[["n"]], b=i[["b"]], c=i[["c"]], maximum=T)$maximum 
})
```

Binding the result:

```
mat2 <- cbind(mat, opt)
mat2
      a   b c  n          opt
[1,]  2 1.5 1  2 9.999944e+00
[2,] -2 2.0 1  3 5.575865e-05
[3,]  1 0.5 1 20 5.575865e-05
```